# wrong behaviour of number format

Tags: javascript, reactjs, number-formatting, visual-web-developer

So I'm using the NumberFormat library for building a placeholder, but it doesn't work how I wanted it to work, and I don't find the reason. The behavior of the input field is quite strange. The "$0" which should behave as a placeholder behaves as a character, so if the user types "120", the amount will actually be "1200".

Here's a video of how it works: https://media.giphy.com/media/sptBQiYqQr3B54rJFu/giphy.gif

But the correct behaviour would be to, when there is a 0, and the user inputs a value, the 0 should be replaced (you can check the google calculator, it does that).

```
<NumberFormat
                defaultValue={undefined}
                value={payoutInputValue}
                displayType="input"
                thousandSeparator
                decimalScale={2}
                prefix={getCurrencySymbol(currency)}
                allowLeadingZeros={false}
                allowNegative={false}
                getInputRef={numberInputRef}
                onValueChange={(values) =>
                  setPayoutInputValue(values?.floatValue || undefined)
                }
                disabled={disabled || isLoading}
                isAllowed={isDrawAmountAllowed(0, currency)}
                required
              />
```

and the setPayoutInputValue function:

```
const [payoutInputValue, setPayoutInputValue] = useState<number>(
    payout === 0 && isAmountParamValid ? amountParamParsed : payout
  );
```

I have not much experience with React, so if you could answer with basic terms, that'd be awesome. Thanks!

EDIT: managed to make it work! added placeholder attribute and value={undefined}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the `hintText` prop for `NumberFormat`, also give as an initial value `undefined`.

```
<NumberFormat
  hintText="Some placeholder"
  value={this.state.card}
  customInput={TextField}
  format="#### #### #### ####"
/>
```

Comment: i can't install react-text-field :( is there another way?

Comment: nvm, it worked changing hitnText to placeholder

Comment: Nice! Then please mark as answered the question.